# Specialization of single template argument

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Consider the following code:

```
/* aclass.h */
class AClass
{
public:
    template<size_t N, class Vector>
        void aMethod(const Vector &);
};

/* aclass.inl */
// method for any N
template<size_t N, class Vector>
    void AClass::aMethod(const Vector &) { ... }

// method for N = 1
template<class Vector>
    void AClass::aMethod<1>(const Vector &) { ... }

/* main.cpp */
int main()
{
    AClass inst;
    std::vector<float> data;
    // calls method for any N
    inst.aMethod<20>(data);
    // calls method for N = 1
    inst.aMethod<1>(data);
}
```

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for specializing a single template argument of integer type - and not even sure if it is legal. I looked around a bit, but didn't find anyone with this problem...

These are the errors i get (from msvc):

```
error C2244 : 'AClass::aMethod' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
error C2768 : 'AClass::aMethod' : illegal use of explicit template arguments
```

How would i go on about solving this problem?

Comment: Functions templates cannot be partially specialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template.

To achieve your goal, you could go through a helper class, which can be partially specialized:

```
class AClass;

template<size_t N, class Vector>
struct AMethodHelper {
  static void Do(AClass* pThis, const Vector&) {
    // General for N != 1
  }
};

template<class Vector>
struct AMethodHelper<1, Vector> {
  static void Do(AClass* pThis, const Vector&) {
    // Special for N == 1
  }
};

class AClass
{
public:
    template<size_t N, class Vector>
    void aMethod(const Vector & v) {
      AMethodHelper<N, Vector>::Do(this, v);
    }
};
```

Or, you could use two overloads selected with SFINAE:

```
class AClass
{
public:
    template<size_t N, class Vector>
    typename enable_if<N!=1>::type aMethod(const Vector &) {
          // General for N != 1
    }
    template<size_t N, class Vector>
    typename enable_if<N==1>::type aMethod(const Vector &) {
        // Special for N == 1
    }
};
```

Or, I suppose, you could just have one method with `if (N == 1)` inside. I suspect any decent compiler would be smart enough to eliminate dead code in any given instantiation.